# "Public address system" in Russian

Tags: терминология

How do they refer in Russian to a public address system in the department store?

I looked up some possible terms in a dictionary and found these two: "система оповещения" and "трансляция", but I am not sure.

"Система оповещения" seems to me to be referring more to the public address system in streets (like that in case of war). In other words, it is bigger in scale than a public address system in a department store or in a school.

And "трансляция" seems to be more about a radio, that is, wireless broadcast.

Comment: Звуковое объявление. Probably, _служба звуковых объявлений_ about a system in a public place. Пример: расценки на коммерческие объявления в метро: http://www.reklama-metro.com/price/reklama-metro-sankt-peterburg-zvuk-price-RP-Biznes.pdf Many other examples can be googled.

Comment: _Система (звукового) информирования_ (напр. пассажиров): https://docplayer.ru/54317993-Sistema-informirovaniya-passazhirov-v-aeroportah.html

Comment: I guess **трансляция** is correct, but old fashioned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's *громкая связь*.

> Как рассказать о событиях на вашем стенде? Легко!
>   Дайте объявление по громкой связи в павильоне выставки.
>
> В понедельник я ещё не успела сменить сапоги на туфли, как по громкой связи меня вызвали в кабинет главного бухгалтера.
>
> Дженнифер Лоуренс по громкой связи в самолете поддержала будущих победителей Супербоула. Но всем было наплевать.

Note that *громкая связь* also means "speakerphone" (on your phone).

Comment: That's right, but in formal language it's more likely called **система оповещения**, as Misamoto suggested.

Comment: @AlexVB true, but I'd like to point out that "громкая связь" is by no means slang. It can be quite appropriate (not out of place) even in some formal settings.

Answer (score 8):

In a non-formal situation you would just use "громкоговоритель" (loudspeaker).

"Система оповещения" would still be the formal name of the system that's used in, for example, a fire at a supermarket. Russian [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) states that there are difference scales of such systems, and supermarket one would be "object" scale. I'm not sure there's a formal name for a loudspeaker that would call a worker to his workplace and things like that, I'm not even sure it's a separate system from emergency ones and not just a microphone wired in it.

Comment: the most specific word I can think of for a loudspeaker that exists to boss you around is "матюгальник" (cuss box) in barracks slang ;)

Comment: @AlexP That's an interesting bit of trivia, but I think матюгальник always implies a portable megaphone/bullhorn type of device (with a complementary angry drill sergeant attached on one side), so I'm not sure it's really related to the question.